# How to change background of another div without affecting the first one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I basically have to make this board that has numbers from 1 to 50 and whenever you click on one number, its background changes to a different color. I was able to do it with the first one by making the `<div>` clickable but I don't know how to do it with the second one that is supposed to have the value 2. Here are my codes

```js
var Color = "#FF0";

function theFunction() {
  if (Color == '#FF0') {
    Color = '#F00';
  } else {
    Color = '#FF0';
  }

  document.getElementById('choose').style.backgroundColor = Color;

}
```

```css
div#gameboard {
  background: #CCC;
  border: #999 2px solid;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 70px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameboard">
  <div id="choose" style="width:240px; height:150px; margin-left:30px; margin-top:50px; background-color:#FF0; cursor: pointer; font-size:130px; text-align:center;" onclick="theFunction();">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="chose" style="width:240px; height:150px; margin-left:30px; margin-top:50px; background-color:#FF0; cursor: pointer; font-size:130px; text-align:center;" onclick="theFunction();">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

So what shall I do for the second div? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to remove the id's from your "number" divs, move all your styling code to CSS, and be sure to pass in `this` to the onclick event so you know which number div was clicked. You can then add a `clicked` class that turns the background red when applied and your JavaScript simply toggles the addition/removal of the `clicked` class.

```js
function theFunction(e) {
  e.classList.toggle("clicked");
}
```

```css
#gameboard {
  background: #CCC;
  border: #999 2px solid;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 70px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#gameboard div {
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #FF0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 130px;
  text-align: center;
}

#gameboard div.clicked {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameboard">
  <div onclick="theFunction(this);">
    1
  </div>
  <div onclick="theFunction(this);">
    2
  </div>
</div>
```

This will only work for current, modern browsers. If you need to support older versions of IE (namely < IE10) then you will have to change the JavaScript slightly to test for the existence of the `clicked` class, then add or remove it accordingly.

You might also consider using a framework, like jQuery, where you can easily toggle the add/remove of the `clicked` class and have all the browser-compatible code obscured within the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div id="choose" style="width:240px; height:150px; margin-left:30px; margin-top:50px; background-color:#FF0; cursor: pointer; font-size:130px; text-align:center;" onclick="theFunction();">
```

Answer (score 0):

First you gotta change

```
onclick="theFunction();"
```

to this

```
onclick="theFunction(this);"
```

And then your function will accept a parameter

```
function theFunction(element) {
    [...]
    element.style.backgroundColor=Color;
}
```

That parameter is the clicked element.